# Estimate variance by numerical integration

Tags: numerical-integration

I have a problem to estimate variance by numerical integration. Does anyone know how to solve it? Thanks in advance.

For a random variable X with density $q(x) = e^{(1/3)*|x|^3}$, estimate its variance by numerical integration.

```
q[x_] := Exp[(1/3)*Abs[x]^3]
```

Comment: @Anton Antonov, so, why do you add "-" at q[x_] := Exp[-(1/3)*Abs[x]^3] instead of q[x_] := Exp[(1/3)*Abs[x]^3]. I get 0 at dist /. {ProbabilityDistribution -> Integrate} when I set  q[x_] := Exp[(1/3)*Abs[x]^3]

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, corrected now.

Comment: @AntonAntonov, but if we did not add "-" and let q[x_] := Exp[(1/3)*Abs[x]^3], we could only get "0" when verifying dist / . {ProbabilityDistribution -> Integrate}, which indicate there is something wrong with q[x_] := Exp[(1/3)*Abs[x]^3]

Comment: Without a minus sign in the exponent, the function grows unbounded with either positive or negative `x`. Consequently, it cannot be normalized unless you specify a finite range for `x` or add a minus sign in the exponent.

Comment: @LeslieChiu My edits were just to make your question clearer and more ready for investigation. Please, see Bob Hanlon's answer and comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably you intend the distribution to be

```
dist = ProbabilityDistribution[E^(-(1/3)*Abs[x]^3), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
  Method -> "Normalize"]

(* ProbabilityDistribution[(3^(2/3) E^(-(1/3) Abs[\[FormalX]]^3))/(
 2 Gamma[1/3]), {\[FormalX], -∞, ∞}] *)
```

Verifying the normalization

```
dist /. {ProbabilityDistribution -> Integrate}

(* 1 *)
```

Numerically calculating the mean

```
mu = NIntegrate[x PDF[dist, x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 20]

(* 0.*10^-21 *)
```

Comparing with analytic result

```
mu == Mean[dist]

(* True *)
```

Numerically calculating the variance

```
var = NIntegrate[(x - mu)^2 PDF[dist, x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 20]

(* 0.77645821137842039620 *)
```

Comparing with analytic result

```
var == Variance[dist]

(* True *)
```

Comment: Could you get a new estimate for the variance of X by importance sampling using a standard normal proposal?

Comment: @LeslieChiu - I do not know what " importance sampling using a standard normal proposal" means.

Comment: that is another method to simulate and find the variance which should be reduced by importance sampling. Thanks all the same!